# Express public directory cannot be found

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I'm attempting to use Node.js with Express, and I read about the ability to declare a 'public' directory to serve static files out of. I'm attempting to put my bootstrap css/js files in the public directory, but I keep getting 404s.

In express:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
console.log(path.join(__dirname, '../public'));
//Output: D:/app/public
```

In HTML:

```
<script src="http://localhost:6969/app/public/resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Now in my filesystem:

```
D:\app\public //The folder
D:\app\public\resources\bootstrap\js\bootstrap.js //The file that the 404 is on
```

I don't know what else I'm missing. I think I might misunderstand the app.use, or the way this public folder is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a public folder with express, all static files are fetched with that public folder as the root('/'). To remedy this issue,
Change:
`<script src="http://localhost:6969/app/public/resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`

To:
`<script src="/resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script src="resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```